# Spreading a table's partitions across drives

Tags: mysql, partition-table

With nearly a billion rows, we have to split up individual partitions across SSDs with about 4 partitions of them in each SSD.

The table's current schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `a` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `special_key` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `data1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `data2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`special_key`),
  UNIQUE KEY `special_key` (`special_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=4
PARTITION BY KEY (special_key)
PARTITIONS 12;
```

If we'd done this while partitioning initially, the command that works looks like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `a`
partition by key(special_key) PARTITIONS 12  
(
PARTITION p0 ,
PARTITION p1 ,
PARTITION p2 ,
PARTITION p3 DATA DIRECTORY='/media/p1/mysql_table_a',
PARTITION p4 DATA DIRECTORY='/media/p1/mysql_table_a',
PARTITION p5 DATA DIRECTORY='/media/p1/mysql_table_a',
PARTITION p6 DATA DIRECTORY='/media/p1/mysql_table_a',
PARTITION p7 DATA DIRECTORY='/media/p2/mysql_table_a',
PARTITION p8 DATA DIRECTORY='/media/p2/mysql_table_a',
PARTITION p9 DATA DIRECTORY='/media/p2/mysql_table_a',
PARTITION p10 DATA DIRECTORY='/media/p3/mysql_table_a',
PARTITION p11 DATA DIRECTORY='/media/p3/mysql_table_a',
);
```

But now that we've already partitioned this table, is there a way to get MySQL to 'move' specific partitions without re-creating the whole table?

Copying & Symlinking these tables manually works but it's not the ['right' way](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-placing.html) and this is reset on any further alters.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773841/mysql-reorganize-algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is

```
ALTER TABLE `a` REORGANIZE PARTITION
     p0 INTO (PARTITION p0 DATA DIRECTORY='/media/p666/mysql_table_a');
```

what you're looking for?

[Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) suggest it should be safe to run on existing partitions, meaning it won't repartition the whole table.

> ALTER TABLE with ADD PARTITION, DROP PARTITION, COALESCE PARTITION,
>   REBUILD PARTITION, or REORGANIZE PARTITION does not create any
>   temporary tables (except when used with NDB tables); however, these
>   operations can and do create temporary partition files.

...

> REORGANIZE operations copy only changed partitions and do not touch unchanged ones.

Comment: Rephrasing: Does the command simply copy the '.ibd' file or recreate it row-by-row?

Comment: I kind of don't understand what difference between the two you expect. (Besides some performance)